# Invalid member type plugin causing build failure

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk

Today, I opened my Android Studio and tried to build an APK but without changing anything, I got this error: `Invalid type in member Type: com/google/gms/googleservices/GoogleServicesPlugin$PluginType; android studio`

and here are some other errors that the compiler throws at me:

[image: errors]

I tried deleting the 0.jar file from the respective folder and see if that fixes one of the errors but nothing. Any ideas? I don't get what I should change or what I did wrong since I didn't mess around with anything.

EDIT:

```
public class DokkanCardsApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            // Fix for the Full Screen Activities bug with Android O
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your view from Android to Project from top of the left side of your Android Studio and delete `.gradle` file maybe it helps you.
And I think you have to enable `multidex` in your application too.

Do it like this:

```
android {
        defaultConfig {
           multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Second, add this to four dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

And finally make an application class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

And finally don't forget to add your application class into your manifest like this:

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

UPDATE:

Your application class should be like this:

```
public class DokkanCardsApplication extends Application {


  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

        // Fix for the Full Screen Activities bug with Android O
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like all i had to do was add the dependency for multidex (the rest had already been done). Just one note, when i tried Overriding the attachBaseContext method in my custom application class, the IDE said that there is no such overridable class.Do you know why that is?

Comment: did you extend your class from Application or some other kind of that?

Comment: you can extend your class of ```MultiDexApplication``` too and then it's not necessary to override your ```attachBaseContext```.
But I don't know where is the problem with your application class that you cant override your ```attachBaseContext```.
if it's possible post your  class

Comment: Sorry about my delay, I Updated my answer with your application class